# Explaining the title of the movie "Coogan's Bluff" (1968)

Tags: title, coogans-bluff

Why is "Coogan's Bluff" the title of the 1968 Clint Eastwood movie "Coogan's Bluff"? What does the title refer to? What was the Clint Eastwood character Coogan's bluff in the movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coogan%27s_Bluff_(film)):

> The name of the film itself is a reference to a New York City natural
> landmark, Coogan's Bluff, a promontory in upper Manhattan overlooking
> the site of the former long-time home of the New York Giants baseball
> club, the Polo Grounds, with a double-meaning derived from the name of
> the lead character.

There is a scene in the movie in which the character Julie talks about Coogan's Bluff.